# overflow: scroll; jquery keeps scrolling until some point, after it stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just keep appending, you will see the latest chat message appears, but after some point it stops scrolling down automatically. How can I fix this? Thanks.

**http://jsfiddle.net/VMcsU/**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("<div>").html("text").appendTo("#chat1");
    $('#chat1').scrollTop($('#chat1').height())
});
```

Comment: because `chat1`'s height is `100px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight)

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/tLfv7/)

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("<div>").html("text").appendTo("#chat1");
    $('#chat1').scrollTop($('#chat1')[0].scrollHeight)
});
```